# Not found for CancelIoEx in Windows xp

Tags: sockets

`Socket TCP`, in C++ with QT, compiled in `MinGW 32` bits for pc windows XP service pack 1.

> Error  :   not found for CancelIoEx   "No se encuentra el punto de
>   entrada del procedimiento CancelIoEx en la biblioteca de vinculos
>   dinamicos kernel.32.dll"

Answer (score 1):

The [**CancelIoEx**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/cancelioex-func) function wasn't added until Windows Vista:

> ### Requirements
>
> **Minimum supported client**: Windows Vista [desktop apps | UWP apps]

That is why you cannot find it in Windows XP.